# ORMLite get Could not get next result for class for all columns

Tags: android

I'm using ORMlite library in android and I get this error random I get this error when I'm using this method to get all column from database.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get next result for class [Ljava.lang.String;
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.next(SelectIterator.java:183)

```
GenericRawResults<String> idKeyResults =
    mouvementQuery.queryRaw("select idMouvement from Mouvement", mapperMvts);

GenericRawResults<String> idValsResults =
    mouvementQuery.queryRaw("select idCategorie from Mouvement", mapperMvts); 


//
if (idKeyResults != null
        && idValsResults != null) {
    //
    List<String> keyCategories = idKeyResults.getResults();
    List<String> valCategories = idValsResults.getResults();

enter code here
```

Comment: Did you figure this out ? I'm having the same issue